# Using Google Compute Engine for my wordpress site. How do I enable DNS for my domain?

Tags: wordpress, dns, google-compute-engine

I enabled http on my instance so I can now browse to my wordpress website.
I assigned the instance a static IP address.

How do I point my domain to the DNS of this instance with the static IP address I now have?

Answer (score 1):

This is usually done by your domain registar. Most registars have a control panel from which you can change DNS records. You have to change the A-record to match your static IP.

Comment: I'm familiar with that.  There's nothing I need to configure on the Google Compute Engine side?

Comment: No, the DNS server from your provider will tell vistors that the A-record they are looking for can be found at the static IP you provided. After that, the browser takes care of retrieving the data from the IP. Once you've set up the static IP at the instance, you're done there.